# How to get multi param with Dancer2?

Tags: perl, param, dancer

I'm trying to get array in `param`, everything works well with single data, but not for array...

client-side (list of parameters sent from the browser):

```
list[1] null
list[2] 2
list[3] 10
list[4] null
```

server-side:

```
any ['get','post'] => '/save_list' => sub {
  my $items = param ('list');
  #result = null, mb is  only the first element
  #my $items = param ('list[]');
  #result = null
  #my @items = param ('list[]');
  #result = empty
  #my @items = param ('list');
  #result = empty   
};
```

Where Am I Wrong?

My version Dancer2-0.155004

Comment: What is the called URL ?

Comment: finally: https://github.com/PerlDancer/Dancer2/issues/726

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [DSL keyword `parameters`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dancer2::Core::Request#parameters) will return a [Hash::MultiValue](https://metacpan.org/pod/Hash::MultiValue) object that you can use to access those in Dancer2.

```
any ['get','post'] => '/save_list' => sub {
  my @items = parameters->get_all('list');
  foreach my $item ( @items ) {
    do_stuff($item);  
  }
};
```

Comment: After reading the github issue, I see you actually got them to implement this. Well done. I'll leave this answer for reference as the question showed up as related to a similar D1 question.